# Java Streams filter two Lists of Maps using ifPresentOrElse()

Tags: java, list, hashmap, java-stream

I have two lists:

```
Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();

map1.put("age", "30");
map1.put("name", "john");

Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("age", "31");
map1.put("name", "marry");

List<Map<String, String>> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.add(map1);
list1.add(map2);

Map<String, String> map3 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("age", "40");
map1.put("name", "mike");

Map<String, String> map4 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("age", "41");
map1.put("name", "terry");

List<Map<String, String>> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.add(map3);
list1.add(map4);
```

I want to iterate through the `list1` and find if *age* is found. If age is found, it should return the *name*.

If the target *age* is not found in the `list1`, I want to iterate through the `list2`, and if the result was found return the *name*.

I'm thinking of something along these lines:

```
list1.stream()
    .filter(a -> a.get("age").equals("40"))
    .findAny()
    .ifPresentOrElse()
```

How can I achieve this using streams?

Answer (score 4):

## Use the Power of Objects

The usage of maps in your code is an example of abuse of collections. Storing the data in such a way is inconvenient and error-prone.

Instead of trying to substitute a domain object with a `Map`, you need to define a `class` (or a `record`).

It'll give you many advantages that you're depriving yourself by using maps:

- Ability to use the proper type for every property instead of keeping everything as strings;
- No need to perform parsing;
- Self-explanatory method names instead of hard-coded string keys, and your code will not fail because you've misspelled a key;
- The code is easier to read and maintain.

For the sake of simplicity and conciseness, I'll go with a Java 16 [*record*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/language/records.html):

```
public record Person(String name, int age) {}
```

And now we have two lists of `Person` instead of two lists of maps.

To implement the logic when we're starting with examining the first list and only if a result was not found we proceed by iterating through the second list, we can make use of the Java 9 method [`or()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/Optional.html#or(java.util.function.Supplier)) defined by `Optional`. While invoked on the optional object containing a value, `or()` returns the same optional, otherwise it'll return an optional produced by a supplier provided as an argument.

For convenience, we can define a method that takes a `List<Person>` and the target `age` and returns an optional result.

```
public static Optional<Person> getPersonByAge(List<Person> people, int age) {
    return people.stream().filter(pers -> pers.age() == age).findFirst();
}
```

We can make this method reusable by making it generic. So it would expect a `List<T>` and a `Predicate<T>` as its arguments.

```
public static <T> Optional<T> getPersonByAge(List<T> people,
                                             Predicate<T> predicate) {
    
    return people.stream().filter(predicate).findFirst();
}
```

And that how we can apply it:

```
List<Person> list1 = List.of(new Person("john", 30), new Person("marry", 31));
List<Person> list2 = List.of(new Person("mike", 40), new Person("terry", 41));
        
Predicate<Person> age40 = pers -> pers.age() == 40;
    
String name = getPersonByAge(list1, age40)
    .or(() -> getPersonByAge(list2, age40))
    .orElseThrow()
    .name();
    
System.out.println(name);
```

*Output:*

```
mike
```

[*A link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/tfI)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the map so you can:

```
Optional<String> nameByAge = getNameByAge(list1, "40").or(()->getNameByAge(list2, "40"));

public static Optional<String> getNameByAge(List<Map<String, String>> people, String age) {
        return people.stream().filter(person -> person.get("age").equals(age)).findAny().map(person-> person.get("name"));
    }
```